# GRASS 6.4 Reinstallation for Ubuntu

Tags: grass-gis, installation, ubuntu, command-line, compatibility

I need to reinstall GRASS 6.4 on this Ubuntu computer due to compatibility issues. I had installed GRASS 6.4 a few weeks ago to work with a simulation program. I used the command

```bash
apt-get install grass
```

as explained at the website https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/linux/. Later I installed GRASS 7.1 to try to start making compatibility changes to the simulation. After doing this, the simulation no longer worked. I decided to try uninstalling all GRASS and reinstalling GRASS 6.4.

However, when I use the same command at the terminal, it only installs GRASS 7.0. I tried using a repository for GRASS 6, but that installed GRASS 7.1.

What is the simplest method I can use to reinstall GRASS 6.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to completely remove grass 7 you have to use:

```
sudo apt-get purge grass
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge grass
```

Afterward, you need to eliminate this repository of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` because it is the source of GRASS GIS 7.0 (stable):

```
ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grass
```

to install the old grass 6.4

I hope that it helps.

Comment: This worked.  There were some leftover GRASS 7 components after using the "purge grass" command, so I used Synaptic to delete those.  Then, I followed the rest of the directions.  GRASS 6.4 was installed correctly, and the simulation program is working again!  Thank you for your help.